# Most frequent occurrence Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have an object with a column `supervisor`. In `supervisor` there are the following values:

- John
- Mary
- Phil
- John

How can I return John?

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = String()
```

Comment: Please include your Realm model definitions in your question.

Comment: there you go @DávidPásztor

Comment: Only possible if you store an additional table (i mean RealmObject) with this particular data.

Comment: Im thinking some kind of loop across distinct values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Realm Results` implement [RealmCollectionType](https://realm.io/docs/swift/1.0.0/api/Protocols/RealmCollectionType.html#/s:vP10RealmSwift19RealmCollectionType5countSi)

`RealmCollectionType` has `count` property and `max(_:)` aggregate operations.  
What you need to do is something like (the following is pseudocode, won't compile, provided just to show the point):

> results.filter { element in  element.count == results.max(byCount) }.first

Any operation on `Result` object is being performed in `Realm database`, not in device memory.

Comment: maybe, if I got the full bounty.. :-(   .......  I could come out with the code, I'm a bit busy now. If you don't want to wait, check similar query with mongoDB, they did that all the time.  Or somewhere along  'Scala' or other functional languages.

Comment: Sorry I was under time pressure with the bounty. Would still appreciate a full answer and I'm sure lots of other people would too. Not familiar with MongoDB at all

Comment: I don't currently has any `Realm project` set up to play with. And I don't currently have extra time to do that.  But I know it is supported after I looked at the `Result API`.  I have done something similar on both `MongoDB`  and  `Apache Spark` couple years back.  I've give you the `hint`. Play with the Result API and you should be able to find out the right syntax to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch all the `Person` objects associated with your column `supervisor` (a [`List<T>`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html)?), and count the `name` frequencies among those `Person` objects, from where the maximum count naturally follows.

```
var frequencies = [String: Int]()
for person in yourRealmObject.supervisor {
    frequencies[person.name] = (frequencies[person.name] ?? 0) + 1
}

if let mostCommonName = frequencies.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })?.key {
    // ... mostCommonName holds string "John" (if that is most common)
}
```

Naturally more than one name might be the most common one in your column, in which case you might want to return an array of the most common ones

```
if let mostCommonNames = frequencies.values.max()
    .map({ maxCount in frequencies.filter { $0.value == maxCount }.map { $0.key } }) {
    // ... mostCommonNames [String]
}
```

Or, if you're actually looking to count occurrences of the same object (rather than looking at the `name` property: there could e.g. be several different `Person`:s with the `name` `"John"`), you could consider making your `Person` object conform to `Hashable` and count the frequencies of actual unique objects (rather than the frequencies of different *values* of the `name` properties of the object).

```
// Person is Hashable ...
frequencies = [Person: Int]()
for person in yourRealmObject.supervisor {
    frequencies[person] = (frequencies[person] ?? 0) + 1
}

// ...
```

Since `Person` is a reference type, the `key` corresponding to the most common object will be a reference to that object (e.g. the `"John"` `Person`).

---

However, possibly I'm not following your question: please expand it if this is not what you're after.

Comment: I believed @Sam wanted the computing to find `john` as most frequent occurence value being performed in `Realm database`.  Something a `mongoDB` user could do easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Person` and you want to get one of their `Person` supervisors objects matching a given name:

```
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = String()
  let supervisors = List<Person>()

  convenience init(name: String) {
    self.init()
    self.name = name
  }
}

let realm = try! Realm()

var me: Person!

try! realm.write {
  me = Person(name: "Me")
  for supervisor in ["John", "Mary", "Phil"] {
    me.supervisors.append(Person(name: supervisor))
  }
  realm.add(me)
}

let john = me.supervisors.filter("name == 'John'")[0]

print(john)
```

This prints:

```
Person {
  name = John;
  supervisors = RLMArray <0x6080000f2280> (

  );
}
```